# Delete ruby version using rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to delete ruby 2.0.0-p247 using rbenv. I tried rbenv uninstall 2.0.0-p247, but it does not seem to work. It appears again when I go to                  rbenv versions. The version I tried to delete is still there. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have uninstalled Ruby using:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.0.0-p247
```

You need to clean up stale shimmed binaries from the removed version. You can do this by:

```
rbenv rehash
```

Just incase `uninstall` command is not working, you can also manually remove Ruby by:

```
rm -rf ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247
```

just be careful with using `rm -rf`

Comment: How and why should I be careful?

Comment: @JustinLee `rm -rf` will force delete everything recursively for the specified dir. So you should be careful how you are using it. Eg. `rm -rf .` can prove lethal.

Comment: Also, when I use rbenv uninstall 2.0.0-p247, it says "remove /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-247?", what am i supposed to do then?

Comment: preferred way is using `rbenv uninstall 2.0.0-p247` followed by `rbenv rehash`. If that doesn't work go for manual deletion.

Comment: that means: `rm -rf  /Users/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-247`

Comment: Seems like permission is denied when trying any of these. How do I manually delete ruby?